# Where to find artifact in Azure DevOps Custom agent pool

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am using a custom agent pool in Azure DevOps. I have made a build and published the artifact but I want to update a file in artifact without creating a new build. how we can do that in `Publish Artifacts` task it showing that upload `/home/ubuntu/myagent/_work/4/a` to file container: `#/9464/Artifact-Name`.

I am logged in to agent pool server and checked all the directories but I couldn't find the file container location. Can any buddy help me to find the Artifact location in agent pool.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your drop location, you probably can't.  The only way I imagine this would be possible is if you were publishing to a share location instead.

When you publish artifacts (that would be visible from the build summary), those are stored on the Azure DevOps database content tables and are immutable.  As Jane Ma mentioned in a comment out about the local files:

> The directory referenced by $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) is
> cleaned up after each build. [...] you can't edit published artifacts.
> You can get them in agent pool's local file, but all local operations
> are not synced to the Azure DevOps. If you want to do follow-up work
> on this artifact, you need to run a new build to update it.

Comment: Hi Matt, Path to publish is $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in Publish Artifact task. can you guide me what will be the location?

Comment: I guess my point is that you can find the file there, but you've already published.  You can change the file in the agent, but if you've already published the files have been copied to the content tables on the backend of Azure DevOps.  You won't be able to edit them, because I believe they are immutable.  You would have to have edited whatever you wanted to edit prior to publishing.

Comment: @Rajeev Srivastava The directory referenced by Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory is cleaned up after each build. As Matt said, you can't edit published artifacts. You can get them in agent pool's local file, but all local operations are not synced to the Azure DevOps. If you want to do follow-up work on this artifact, you need to run a new build to update it.

Comment: @Matt and Janema-MSFT for your help.